# speed of a curve on a Manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, curves

For a curve, $$c:I\rightarrow M$$ onto a Manifold $M$ and for a chart $(U, \phi)$, and $\phi \circ c = (x^1,...,x^m) $, how does one arrive at the following expression for the derivative: $$\dot{c}=\sum_j \dot{x}^j(\frac{\partial}{\partial\phi^i})\circ c$$

Comment: You mean velocity, not speed. Without a Riemannian metric, there's no way to know the length of the vector (and that's what speed is).

Comment: Ah, thanks. That's an important detail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is an application of the chain rule
\begin{equation}c'(0)f:=(f\circ c)'(0)=\left((f\circ \phi^{-1})\circ (\phi \circ c)\right)'(0)=\sum_{i=1}^m \frac{d}{dt}(\phi \circ c)^i \frac{\partial (f\circ \phi^{-1})}{\partial u^i}=\sum_{i=1}^n\dot{x}^i \frac{\partial}{\partial \phi^i}f,
\end{equation}
where in the last equality the definition of $\frac{\partial}{\partial \phi^i}$ was used.
To get your formula just think the $f$ away.

Comment: thank you. this helped